# Trying to show and hide divs for sequencing effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 divs on the page, I only want to show one at a time.

On load, shows div 1 (and only shows div1, div2 and div3 are hidden),  with 3 options. No matter what option the user picks, I want div 1 to hide, and div 2 to show. Div 2 only has one option, so select the option and div 3 shows.

There are some similar to this question on stackoverflow, but with 3 options to click in div 1, im having trouble seeming to make it work. (i need each with a different value to display what what chosen in div 1 and 2 in div 3)

JSFidle - https://jsfiddle.net/7yuuz8d4/4/

html:

```
<!doctype html>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<body>

 <div class="container">
    <div id="div1">
        <h2>Pick a style</h2>



    <div class="col-md-4">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4f/Simple_triangle.svg/120px-Simple_triangle.svg.png">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#div2" role="button" value="casual">Casual &raquo;</a>
    </div><!--Closes Col-md-4-->

    <div class="col-md-4">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4f/Simple_triangle.svg/120px-Simple_triangle.svg.png">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#div2" role="button" value="street">Street &raquo;</a>
    </div><!--Closes Col-md-4-->

    <div class="col-md-4">
    <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4f/Simple_triangle.svg/120px-Simple_triangle.svg.png">
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#div2" role="button" value="classic">Classic &raquo;</a>
    </div><!--Closes Col-md-4-->
    </div><!--Closes div1-->

    <div id="div2">
    <h3>Measurements</h3>
      <select>
          <option value="tall">tall</option>
          <option value="average">average</option>
          <option value="short">short</option>
        </select> 
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="#div3" role="button">Next &raquo;</a>
    </div><!--Closes div2-->


    <div id="div3">
    <h3>Review</h3>
    <p>Display style and measurements selected:</p>
    <div id="display">

    </div>
    <a class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" href="success.html" role="button">Submit &raquo;</a>
    </div><!--Closes div3-->
    </div><!--Closes container-->

    </body>
```

Jquery -

```
function showDiv(selector){

    //---Select div to show
    var element = $("div#" + selector);

    //---Hide all div except the above div
    $("div[id^='div']").not(element).hide();

  //---Show the div
  element.show();

}

//---When the select changes
$(".btn btn-primary btn-lg").on("click", function(){

    showDiv( $(this).val() );

});

//---Show the first div by default
showDiv("#div1");
```

Thank you in advance, as always you all are a great help!

Comment: You mean that div1 and div3 will appear on load and after select div1 it will disappear and show div2. but div3 always stay there right?

Comment: No, On load only Div1 shows. On select, div 1 disappears, div 2 shows. Again, on select div2 disappears, div 3 shows. I apologize I was no clear with this, I will edit the original post to show as such. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
            $('#div1').show();
            $('#div2').hide();
            $('#div3').hide();

            $('#div1').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
                $('#div1').hide();
                $('#div2').show();
            });

            $('#div2').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
                $('#div2').hide();
                $('#div3').show();
            });
        });
```

Comment: What of my current Jquery do I replace with this? The "$(".btn btn-primary btn-lg").on("click", function(){

 showDiv( $(this).val() );

});" 
part?

Comment: Yes. I edit for on load. At first time you will see just div1. after click a link in div2, div1 will disappear and div2 become to show. after click a link in a div2, div2 will hide and div3 become to show. you don't need showDiv function anymore.

Comment: Well, that worked perfectly. I think i over complicated the code, but i put in yours and everything is working amazingly. You have been a huge help, thank you and I will mark your answer as solving this. Hope you have a great day!

Answer (score 0):

Go through this fiddle may be it can help you -

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7yuuz8d4/21/)

JAVASCRIPT

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#div2').hide();
    $('#div3').hide();
    $(".btn").on("click", function(){
        this1 = $(this).attr('href');
        console.log(this1);
        $('*[id^="div"]').hide();
        $(this1).show();
    });
});
```